# Understanding emacs keys

Tags: key-bindings, modifier-key

I'm vim user and I've just started using emacs with evil. But one thing I'm finding really hard to understand is when do we use `<C-x>`, `<M-x>` etc. I want to understand **when** to use `Control` or `Meta`.

For example in vim, in normal mode `d` is the delete operator and can be combined with text objects like lines and words. So I'm trying to understand if things like `C-x` is bound to say runtime operations etc.

Comment: My advice would be to start at the beginning by running through the Emacs tutorial: start emacs and say `C-h t`. After you've gone through that, at least some of your questions will have been answered.

Comment: FYI: You applied tag `prefix-keys`. Control and Meta keys are modifier keys, not prefix keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about conventions, basically `control` is used for basic/normal editing commands (like `C-k` for `kill-line`) , and `meta` for extended commands (like `M-k` for `kill-sentence`).

There are also conventions for the core features, user space/modes, etc. which are explained (mostly) in the manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html), or blog posts like [this one](https://yiufung.net/post/emacs-key-binding-conventions-and-why-you-should-try-it/) which is more easy to follow for people coming from Vim.

Comment: Thanks for the links, exactly the rabbithole I needed to dive into.